# How to show the number of remaining slides in Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow, numbering

Want the current slide to show how many more slides are left to do.
What I tried - in Master View, I see a `<#>` where the slide number is placed. I tried something like `37-<#>` there, but it does not work. I thought maybe it should be `<37-#>` or something like that, but I cannot type anything inside the angle brackets.

Probably I could do it with a vbasic script, but is not there some simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this is to add a "thermometer bar" to each slide.

There's an example on my PPTFAQ page here:
https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00597_Add_a_-thermometer-_progress_bar_to_each_slide.htm

Near the top of the article, there's a link to the InDezine site, where there's a pre-made add-in to do the job for you.

Comment: Great! Does this work with > 2003 too - pptx, etc.?

Comment: It should; try the macro on the PPTFAQ site. If that doesn't work, let me know. If it does work, then the InDezine add-in should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no good way to meet your needs.

PowerPoint can number your slides for you automatically, but it can't automatically show a count. Additionally, there is no way to count the remaining pages.

As a workaround, You can modify the settings in the Slide Master:

1.On the View tab, in the Master Views group, click Slide Master, and then click the slide master thumbnail.

2.Position modification in the following image (the PPT in my example has three pages in total)

[image]

3.Numbering slides this way does not calculate the total number of slides in your presentation automatically, so you’ll need to enter the total manually, in place of the "3". If you later add slides, you’ll need to update the total manually as well.

4.Finally, we get the following example:

[image]

More information:

[Show the slide number and total number of slides on every slide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-slide-number-and-total-number-of-slides-on-every-slide-e62b363a-a5c4-413e-b7b7-52c1a4d9dd02?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that much, but I still asked this because when I am presenting I would like to absolutely minimize any distracting calculations - even trivial subtraction of numbers.